# How to open nodejs app from browser link or prompt

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, electron

I have created a desktop app using react, nodejs, express and electron. What I want to add next is, to open it from a browser( like when we click on zoom or ms-teams link it prompts us to open a pre-installed desktop application). I want to add a similar functionality where I can open my desktop app from the browser link .I have searched for npm libraries that might help but couldn't find any.I am using `yarn run dev` to run the app.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install open
var opn = require('open');
open('http://Google.com');
```